# Using Log4net to send email through smtp, email never received

Tags: asp.net, logging, smtp, log4net, error-logging

To perform error logging for my WebAPI application, I am using Log4net. I have two log4net appenders, a SmtpEmail appender that uses another server equipped with smtp to send the error-notice email, and a FileAppender directed to a local .txt file. My issue is that my FileAppender is logging everything in my log.txt file as expected, but the SmtpEmail appender is not working. Emails are not received, and I don't get any error messages. Something I noticed is that it would take a long time for DOMConfigurator.Configure() to return, and after it returns, I am often left with many of the same running processes continuing off that return. Any ideas as to what's wrong, or anything I can do to monitor if the calls to the smtp server (referred to below as "baz.bar.com") is going through?

Here is the relevant log4net code in the .config file:

```
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />



<log4net>
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="log-file.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <to value="foo@bar.com" />
  <from value="foo@bar.com" />
  <subject value="Write to AX Error" />
  <smtpHost value="baz.bar.com" />
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <lossy value="false" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
    <threshold value="WARN"/>
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%newline%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value ="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref ="FileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref ="SmtpAppender"/>
</root>
```

I am using Unity. I doubt this is the issue, since my FileAppender is working, but here is the code regardless:

```
    private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ILog>().RegisterInstance(LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ILog)));

        return container;
    }



    private ILog _log;

    public LERService(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }
```

Here are my calls to the log within a function of LERService:

```
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _log.Fatal("Cannot submit to client with following exception: " + e.Message, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that there are some authorizations I haven't been providing.

This link provides a way to check that the email is sending.
http://david.gardiner.net.au/2008/11/log4nets-smtpappender-with-multiple.html

Comment: Still can't get my mail to send. Any other advise on what I could possibly check?